# Facing error while starting Intershop PWA server locally

Tags: progressive-web-apps, intershop

Inprocess to setup local PWA locally, I created environment.local.ts file with local configuration and tried to start PWA using command ng s -c local and now getting below error.

Please suggest !

> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@wishtack/reactive-component-loader/dist/reactive-component-loader/fesm5/wishtack-reactive-component-loader.js
>   226:65-83 "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in
>   '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@wishtack/reactive-component-loader/dist/reactive-component-loader/fesm5/wishtack-reactive-component-loader.js
>   226:175-183 "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@wishtack/reactive-component-loader/dist/reactive-component-loader/fesm5/wishtack-reactive-component-loader.js
>   226:195-203 "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@wishtack/reactive-component-loader/dist/reactive-component-loader/fesm5/wishtack-reactive-component-loader.js
>   226:215-223 "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@wishtack/reactive-component-loader/dist/reactive-component-loader/fesm5/wishtack-reactive-component-loader.js
>   226:248-256 "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
>   ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js): Error: Node Sass does not
>   yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported
>   runtime (79) For more information on which environments are supported
>   please see: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.12.0
>       at module.exports (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
>       at Object. (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at Object.sassLoader (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:301:20
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
>       at runSyncOrAsync (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
>       at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4
>       at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:39:13)
>       at processResource (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
>       at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
>       at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
>       at loadLoader (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
>       at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
>       at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
>       at loadLoader (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
>       at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
>       at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
>       at loadLoader (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
>       at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
>       at runLoaders (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
>       at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:280:3)
>       at NormalModule.build (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:427:15)
>       at Compilation.buildModule (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:635:10)
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1021:12
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:405:6
>       at C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13
>   ERROR in
>   ./src/app/shared/common/components/loading/loading.component.scss
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>   Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment:
>   Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (79) For more information on
>   which environments are supported please see:
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.12.0
>       at module.exports (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
>       at Object. (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at Object.sassLoader (C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@wishtack/rx-scavenger/dist/scavenger.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es/map' in
>   'C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules@wishtack\rx-scavenger\dist'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@wishtack/rx-scavenger/dist/scavenger.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'core-js/modules/es.array.includes' in
>   'C:\ProgressiveWebApp\pwa\node_modules@wishtack\rx-scavenger\dist'

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: What versions are you using?
`node --version`
`npm --version`
`ng --version`

Answer (score 2):

Check the versions of node and npm by using:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

Compare with the required versions declared in package.json in the root folder of the project:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.16.0",
    "npm": "~6.9.0"
  },
```

Update node or npm if necessary.